# How to run a perl script with arguments

Tags: command-line, scripts, perl

I'm pretty new with Ubuntu and Linux and I need some help in order ton run a perl script. It may sound silly, but I need to run a perl (.pl) file, using a specific argument. The key is that when I run the command ("perl file.pl -ARGUMENT"), perl interprets the argument as part of the perl command, instead of part of the script. What can I do in order to "say" perl the argument is destinated to the script?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--` is commonly used to indicate end of options, in this case

```
perl -- file.pl -ARGUMENT
```

This is explained in the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

> A -- signals the end of options and disables further option
>   processing. Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames and
>   arguments.